# Not able to fetch element from dom using xpath

Tags: angular, selenium, xpath

[image]

Not able to fetch element from the dom using xpath

```html
<input bsdatepicker="" class="form-control font-size-normal ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" id="endDate" name="endDate" placement="top" type="text">
```

The element value is not available in the html code the UI for the above element contains following following value "01/14/2019" but not able to fetch the values.

Even tried to search the element value "01/14/2019" in the entire dom using Ctrl+F but still the value is not saved anywhere in the html dom

Comment: I'm very confused. Are you not able to fetch the `input[@name='line_manager']` element or the date picker you posted in your code example?

Comment: Yes because the the text value is not available inside that I'm not sure if it is hidden.

Comment: You answer to my question doesn't make sense. Which element are you unable to find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `element.getAttribute("value")` and you will get the value which is visible on the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

You want to get value of the input, to do it:

In Chrome console:

```
document.querySelector("#endDate").value
```

Selenium Python:

```
end_date = driver.find_element_by_id("endDate").get_attribute("value")
```

Selenium Java:

```
String endDate = driver.findElement(By.id("endDate")).getAttribute("value");
```